# how to Run an external vbs file for particular excel file

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have written a vbs code as

```
Sub rectangle()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 200, 100).TextFrame
        .Characters.Text = "This is a rectangle"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        ChDir "D:"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\Book.xls", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("F5").Select
End Sub
```

but am getting error as

```
script: D:\test.vbs
Line: 10
Char: 36
Error: Expected statement
Code: 800A0400
Source: Microsoft VBscript Compilation error
```

I have pasted the excel file and vb file in *D* drive. can anyone correct me ?

Comment: The above is not vbs code... It is vba code. Can you share the vbs code? or are you running the above VBA code from a `.vbs` file?

Comment: The reason why you get the error is because VBScript doesn't support named parameters (`FileFormat:=...`) and also doesn't know about constants that are pre-defined in Excel (`xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do in a `.vbs` file.

```
Const xlHAlignCenter = -4108
Const xlVAlignCenter = -4108
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52
Const msoShapeRectangle = 1

Dim oXLApp, oXLWB, oXLWs

Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'<~~ I am adding a new workbook for demonstration purpose. 
'<~~ You can open one if you want
Set oXLWB = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add 
Set oXLWs = oXLWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

oXLApp.Visible = True

With oXLWs
    With .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 200, 100).TextFrame

        .Characters.Text = "This is a rectangle"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter

    End With
End With

oXLWB.SaveAs "D:\Book.xls", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , , False
```